# json2csv nodejs using newline delimiter

Tags: node.js

My JSON object is newline delimited and looks something like this:

```
[
    {"car": {"make": "Audi", "model": "A3"}, "price": 4000,"color": "blue"}
    {"car": {"make": "BMW", "model": "F20"},"price": 35000,"color": "black"}
    {"car": {"make": "Porsche", "model": "9PA AF1"},"price": 60000,"color": "green"}
]
```

**EDIT: I need node to read in a newline from the JSON file. Not output a newline. it's an extremely large JSON file where each object is delimited by a newline as opposed to a ','**

Comment: you shouldnt need a delimiter for that.  Which json2csv library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you need the delimiter field.  Try

```
json2csv({ data: myCars, fields: fields }, function(err, csv) { ... }
```

Example from the docs : https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv

```
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var fields = ['car', 'price', 'color'];
var myCars = [
  {
    "car": "Audi",
    "price": 40000,
    "color": "blue"
  }, {
    "car": "BMW",
    "price": 35000,
    "color": "black"
  }, {
    "car": "Porsche",
    "price": 60000,
    "color": "green"
  }
];

json2csv({ data: myCars, fields: fields }, function(err, csv) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('file saved');
  });
});
```

creates output file :

```
car, price, color
"Audi", 40000, "blue"
"BMW", 35000, "black"
"Porsche", 60000, "green"
```

Comment: my actual json file is extremely large (200,000+) lines, where each line is a new object. So its not delimited by commas. My other option would be to read it in and input commas, but that seems a bit difficult

Comment: Then it isn't valid JSON and you likely won't be able to use a JSON parser.  Instead read in each line and parse JSON on the lines individually.